# Reflections for REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, reflection

I'm trying to build a (as close as it gets) generic REST API to simplyfy all the standard CRUD rest calls. For example I'd like to write one `read` method

```
models.{Entity}.findById(id)
  .exec(function(err, entity) {
    res(err, entity)
  }
```

`{Entity}` should be dynamically filled with a param from the rest call e.g.:

```
GET /api/v1/entity/:id/:type
GET /api/v1/entity/1234567890/user
```

Obviously I could do a semi-generic solution like this:

```
if (type === 'user') var query = models.User;
```

But that not really a nice solution in my opinion.

**Questions**

Is there an easy way to implement this and would this be viable on a bigger application? Cause everything I know about reflections from other languages their performance isn't that great.

Has anyone other recommendations on how I could implement such a framework?

**Solution:**

just like Daniel suggested I created a Map

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('user', models.User);
```

Comment: thanks, sometimes the answer is just too easy to see for me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection performance is all over the map when it comes to different reflection techniques, different languages, different language implementations, underlying hardware/OS platforms. While Java has been notoriously poor, other languages incur negligible overhead. TLDR: I wouldn't rule it out unless you have evidence it will really slow you down.

In this case, being JavaScript, I think you can just do `models[name.toLowerCase()]`, it's the same as `models.User` and so on, but generic.

If there really was a cost to reflection, you could still handle it generically by [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result, i.e. compute it once generically and cache the resulting class indefinitely.

Comment: thank you for your insight, I'll stick with your solution for now!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve a problem that can be avoided. If your server would provide a REST API instead of an HTTP API (know the difference!), you would not need to construct URLs because the server would tell you what you can do next through hypermedia controls in the response. Take a read on HATEOAS and hypermedia if you are interested.
As hypermedia is all about the MIME-type of the responses, a generic client is usually built around a single MIME-type. (To name a few: HAL, UBER, Siren, Collection+JSON).

Comment: Thank you for your response! for the moment I'll use mahemoff's solution, but I'll definately read more about rest vs http api (at the moment I'm not quite sure of the difference) and HATEOS.

Comment: HTTP is a protocol whereas REST is an architectural style. You get many of the constraints that are defined by REST for free if you build your system with HTTP. However, you also need to do some additional work, if you want your API to be RESTful (= honor all constraints defined by REST and benefit from the properties that are thereby introduced into your system).

Comment: REST and HTTP evolved alongside each other. A REST API is a special case of a HTTP API - many would say it's an HTTP API done right.

Comment: I did some reading today on that topic. I think I'll try to implement a "true" restful api and see how it goes. thanks for your input :)